# Why my component is not updated as the state from context was changed?

Tags: reactjs

I'm newbie at React. 
I have App.js(grandparent), CardWrapper.js(parent which has some styles), Card.js(child), AddressSearchComponent.js and Context.js which has a common state and reducer function.
I want all Cards updated newly when the address is changed.
Every component referencing a context is re-rendered when a state in the context is changed as I know.
But in my app CardWrapper was rendered just once at first
and not re-rendered a state was changed.
How can I make CardWrapper is re-rendered when list_for_cards is updated?
(Sorry for that my English is awful.)

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { ContextProvider } from './Context.js';
import AddressSearchComponentfrom './AddressSearchComponent';
import CardWrapper from './CardWrapper';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <ContextProvider>
        <AddressSearchComponent></AddressSearchComponent>
      </ContextProvider>
      <section>
        <ContextProvider>
           <CardWrapper></CardWrapper>
        </ContextProvider>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**AddressSearchComponent.js**

```
import { useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { StateContext, DispatchContext } from './Context.js';

async function getData(...) {
    const ret = await axios.get(...);
    return ret.data;
}

function AddressSearchComponent() {
    const state = useContext(StateContext);
    const dispatch = useContext(DispatchContext);
    
    window.state = state; // for debug

    /* useEffect changing state options when selected country is changed */
    /* useEffect changing city options when selected state is changed */
    /* useEffect changing list_for_cards state when city is changed */

    const onChange = ({name, value}) => {
        dispatch({type: 'SET', name, value});
    }

    return (
        <div>
            /* a selectbox for country options */
            /* a selectbox for state options */
            /* a selectbox for city options * /
        </div>
    )
}

export default AddressSearchComponent;
```

**Context.js**

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';

const initialState = {
   currentCountry: '',
   countryList: [],
   currentState: '',
   stateList:[],
   currentCity: '',
   cityList: [],
   list_for_cards: []
}

function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET':
            return {
                ...state,
                [action.name]: action.value
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export const StateContext = React.createContext();
export const DispatchContext = React.createContext();

export function ContextProvider({children}) {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    
    return (
        <StateContext.Provider value={state}>
            <DispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
                {children}
            </DispatchContext.Provider>
        </StateContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

**CardWrapper.js**

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import Card from "./Card";
import { StateContext } from './Context';

function CardWrapper() {
    const { list_for_cards } = useContext(StateContext);
    return (
        <>
        {
            list_for_cards.map(item=> 
                <Card item={item}></Card>
            )
        }
        </>
    ) 
    
}

export default CardWrapper;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, In AddressSearchComponent you only want to update state that comes from select boxes (so selected country, state and city - in your state they). But you need to add these new values to the list_for_cards as well, and you have to update your list state in the reducer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a minor problem with your app.js

You are wrapping `<AddressSearchComponent/> & <CardWrapper />` with `<ContextProvider />` but in wrong way. Both of your compoent should inside one warpper.

It should be wrapped like the following.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ContextProvider } from './Context';
import AddressSearchComponentfrom './AddressSearchComponent';
import CardWrapper from './CardWrapper';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <ContextProvider>
        <AddressSearchComponent />
        <CardWrapper />
      </ContextProvider>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component